# Can't Kill SPID "Transaction Rollback in Progress"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an uncommitted statement in perptual rollback mode in my database. When I try to kill the SPID associated with this statement, I get the following error:

> transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.
>   Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.

This uncommitted statement is causing users to not be able to view the DB's table, view, and procedure trees. How do I stop this SPID?

Comment: How long did the queries in the transaction take to run and how long has the rollback been going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncommitted transaction was a database backup.  There is a known bug (along with MS Hotfix) where the backup sometimes hangs up.  Restarting the cluster fixed the issue

Comment: Having the same problem.  As far as I know there is no hotfix for this.  I've located the bug page but it say's it's closed.  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/187192/openquery-to-linked-server-hangs-leaving-spid-with-open-tran-that-cannot-be-killed-then-templog-ldf-grows-without-limit-requires-sql-server-restart-on-production-servers Can you please link the hotfix?

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread, it seems, if it is started you can't kill it with command. Only if you are making your db offline.

[MSDN forum link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/4a15077f-415a-4ccf-8d05-fe5e4d4f45f9)

Comment: Any by making it offline you have to continue rollback when it comes back. So it does not help. This answer is the solution though: There is none.