# how do I kill UOW locks?

Tags: t-sql

I have two locks in my database I cannot kill.
when I type

`KILL '8A551D5D-887D-4776-AEB3-F603A4CDF0E0'`

I get an error saying:

> Distributed transaction with UOW {8A551D5D-887D-4776-AEB3-F603A4CDF0E0} is rolling back: estimated rollback completion: 0%, estimated time left 0 seconds.

It's been like that for 24 hours now, so I believe that the completion level will not change.

when I try to kill the other one I get the error saying:

> There is a connection associated with the distributed transaction with UOW {6B820CA6-5836-4CCB-BBA6-C3ED615EA933}. First, kill the connection using KILL SPID syntax.

I tried to kill all the connections using the following script:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

But the script never ends.

How do I kill these locks?

Comment: Are there any blocked processes?

Comment: you mean some database processes? I don't even know how to check that.

Comment: Run 'sp_who2'. That will list all processes - there's a column 'blkby' that shows the SPID of any process that is blocking other processes. If there are any numbers in the Blkby column, then there are blocked processes. This will tell you whether your locks are hanging around because they are blocked by another process.

Comment: blkby column is empty totally empty

Comment: What does sp_lock show?

Comment: Is it possible that this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216866/cant-kill-spid-transaction-rollback-in-progress?rq=1  is your problem?

Comment: didn't find it before... in fact I wasn't entirely sure what I should google for, but yeah, it looks similar. still, I cannot restart the cluster right now. I'll have to wait for a few hours before I can try it out.

Comment: It makes sense - I was trying to figure out why ALTER... WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE was blocked and a hung backup process would make sense.